# PHP + HTML if function exists shorthand

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create an `<a>` tag with a PHP function that returns a image source with its html.

My code is currently this:

```
if (returnString('image')) : echo '<img src="'.returnString('image').'" />'; endif;
```

In which my intended final output would be:

```
<img src="http://..." />
```

But its only returning this:

```
"http://..."
```

Which is only the string. Why is this so?

EDIT: I'd actually like to add that **I want to check if the function exists** (if its null there should be any echo-ing), which is why I have the `if` at the start.

It works if I don't check for the function like this:

```
echo '<img src="'; returnString('image'); echo '" />';
```

Comment: If it's a one line `if` you don't need that syntax just `if (condition) expression;`

Comment: can you give complete code related? but it seems you are confusing between echo and return. if a function return everything should be returned not echo.

Comment: @elclanrs you mean `if (returnString('image')) echo '<img src="'.returnString('image').'" />'; endif;` like this, right? but without the `:`, i'm getting a syntax error.

Comment: @SumitGupta this is a `if` in a `elseif`. Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: hey forget the if for a moment: echo '<img src="'.returnString('image').'" />'; what does it echo without if condition ?

Comment: @Deepanshu hey, that worked. but I'm trying to check for the function so that if it contains nothing, it wont echo.

Comment: make sure the returnString function is returning a string without quotes :)

Comment: ahh it's working now. turns out my `if` was actually checking for an object instead of a string. meaning my `if` wasn't `returnString`, but  an object...

Comment: why dont use normal {} brackets instead of colon and moreover try to check using else that where the flow is going

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `:` and `endif` here.

Try this:

```
if (returnString('image')) echo '<img src="'.returnString('image').'" />';
```

Alternatively, you could store the return value in a variable (as mplungjan suggested above) and use that in your code (more readable, IMO). That way, you can avoid your function from being called twice.

```
$src = returnString('image');
if (isset($src)) echo '<img src="'.$src.'" />';
```

> I'd actually like to add that I want to check if the function exists, which is why I have the if at the start.

There's a built-in function, exactly for the same purpose -- [`function_exists()`](http://php.net/function_exists)

You can do the following:

```
if (function_exists('returnString')) {
    $src = returnString('image');
    echo '<img src="'.$src.'"/>';
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @RenoYeo: What do you mean *same thing*?

Comment: @AmalMurali still returning a src string... I can't find the `<img>` anywhere. by the way, i edited the question.

Comment: @RenoYeo: glad to have been of help. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = returnString('image');
if (isset($str)) echo '<img src="'.$str.'" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
<?PHP 
$s="http://www.sagmart.com/image/logoes.png";

if($s) {
echo '<img src="'.$s.'" />';
}
?>
```

I dont have no idea about you returnString('image') so i used the new variable.

remove the endif in the last.

Comment: returnString('image') returns, like in your example, `"http://www.sagmart.com/image/logoes.png"`.

Comment: ok no issue , you can use like my sample.

just check the output of your functions "returnString".

Answer (score 0):

You say it works when you do:

```
echo '<img src="'; returnString('image'); echo '" />';
```

This code has 3 parts. The first is `echo` and prints `<img src="`. The `returnString()` function apparently does it's own printing. The last is also `echo` and prints `" />`.

But you say it wont inside the `if`, when you put it like:

```
echo '<img src="'.returnString('image').'" />';
```

But do mind that here you don't expect the `returnString()` function to do it's own printing. You expect it to just return to you the value to be concatenated. If the function actually does its own printing, as I said above, then you will get the eventual `src` contents to be displayed BEFORE the `<img>` tag